# Create a ranking for a dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have simple data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
```

I want to create a ranking to show how close the ages of two children:

[image]

I appreciate any insights to create the final output efficiently. Thank you

Comment: did you try the `.rank` method?

Comment: No, I calculate the difference, then rank them based on the difference.

Comment: And what does `Ranking` mean?

Comment: The difference value per rows is smaller , the ranking per rows is lower. so 4<5, so 1 for 4 while 2 for 5 when he is tom.

Comment: Why `juli-tom` with a difference `4` has also 2? Why `tom-july` with difference 4 and `nick-juli` with difference 1 both have ranking 1?

Comment: Or does it depend on the previous difference?

Comment: The difference is age difference between two kids, then rank based on the difference. The first two rows is for tom, how close two kids' ages (juli and nick); the next two columns are for nick, then compare with other two kids. Every time we evaluate different kids, so the ranking is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create Difference matrix**

```py
arr = abs(df['Age'].values - df['Age'].values[:, None])
```

**Create dataframe from difference matrix**

```py
df1  = pd.concat((df['Name'], pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = df['Name'])), axis=1)
```

**Melt the dataframe to create Difference column**

```py
df2 = pd.melt(df1, id_vars = ['Name'], value_name='Difference')
```

```
   Name variable  Difference
0   tom      tom           0
1  nick      tom           5
2  juli      tom           4
3   tom     nick           5
4  nick     nick           0
5  juli     nick           1
6   tom     juli           4
7  nick     juli           1
8  juli     juli           0
```

**Remove 0 difference**

```py
 df2 = df2[df2.Difference != 0]
```

```
   Name variable  Difference
1  nick      tom           5
2  juli      tom           4
3   tom     nick           5
5  juli     nick           1
6   tom     juli           4
7  nick     juli           1
```

**Create rank by Difference**

```py
df2['Ranking'] = df2.groupby('variable')['Difference'].rank(method = 'dense', ascending = True)
```

```
   Name variable  Difference  Ranking
1  nick      tom           5      2.0
2  juli      tom           4      1.0
3   tom     nick           5      2.0
5  juli     nick           1      1.0
6   tom     juli           4      2.0
7  nick     juli           1      1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to simplify even more?

Comment: I explained it in 5 lines of code for simplification. You can probably bring it down to 3-4 lines by combining few of them. But I am not sure I can do it in 1 if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I see your points, and I have similar codes. Later I need to create a definition for it. I want to see if I can do it in an efficient way. Thank you.